# Ember: Equivalent of document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener

Tags: ember.js

I need to add a `webkitTransitionEnd` event listener to one of the `DOM` elements in my `EmberView`.

This javascript (DOM) equivalent would be:

```
function transitionEnded() {
    console.log("transition ended");
}

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener(
    "webkitTransitionEnd", 
    this.transitionEnded, 
    true);
```

I've tried the following:

```
var MessageView = Ember.View.extend({
    ...
    transitionEnded: function() {
        console.log("Transition Alert!");
    }, 

    actions: {
        closeMessageWithTransition: function(){
            var elem = document.getElementById('transitionThis');
            elem.addEventListener(
                 "webkitTransitionEnd", this.transitionEnded, true);
            // Trigger the transition here
        }
    ...
```

I've also tried using:

```
this.$("#transitionThis").get(0).addEventListener(...);
```

instead of using:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('transitionThis');
elem.addEventListener(...);
```

but to no avail. The transition happens, but I do not get any events nor do I see errors in the console.

I can confirm that the `document.getElementById` method selects the right element. So, where are my event handlers going?

---

**EDIT 1**: Didn't realize there was an emberjs.jsbin.com. So, here you go:

[Emberjs.jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/awEWUfOd/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

PS: I do realize that the element I'm attaching a listener to ends up getting destroyed later when in `transitionTo('messages')` but I've commented out that bit and still no effect.

---

**EDIT 2**: I've added an alternate method of trying to catch the event using an `EventManager` as outlined in the [Ember.View](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html) docs.

[Alternate Method](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ObUxufi/1/)

Comment: Can you set up an example, feel free to use the template at Emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: @kingpin2k I've set up an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's using animation, not transition, `webkitAnimationEnd` is the appropriate hook.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/awEWUfOd/4/edit